# Appending a text to a variable in Twig

Tags: variables, join, append, twig, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a string in Twig using the ~ (tilde) operator. Here is my case, with the different things I tried :

```
{% set class = 'original_text' %}

{# First try : the most obvious for me, as a PHP dev #}
{% class ~= 'some_other_text' %}

{# Second try #}
{% class = class ~ 'some_other_text' %}

{# Third try #}
{% class = [class, 'some_other_text'] | join(' ') %}

{# Fourth try : the existing variable is replaced #}
{% set class = [class, 'some_other_text'] | join(' ') %}

{# 
    Then do another bunch of concatenations.....
#}
```

None of the above work.

I have some more conditions and need to add some text each time. Something that would work like this :

```
{% set class = 'original_text ' %}

{% class ~= 'first_append ' %}
{% class ~= 'second_append ' %}
{% class ~= 'third_append ' %}
```

And the result for

```
{{ class }}
```

would be :

```
original_text first_append second_append third_append
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Thank you !

**EDIT :** It turned out to be a CSS error, the concatenation went well....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can concatenate a string with a variable using set tag. From your example we can rewrite the lines,

```
{% set class = 'original_text' %}
{% set class = class ~ ' some_other_text'%}
```

And we can show by printing the new *class* variable like this,

```
{{class}}
```

It will Show the out put like this, **original_text some_other_text**

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, there are several concatenations to be done. And if I do one or more additional set class =.... , the previous concatenations are lost

Comment: In fact, it was a CSS error, the concatenation was correctly made... I accept your answer, it was the right thing to do !

Answer (score 1):

Since twig 1.5 you can use [string interpolation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation) which is very usefull, in your case:

```
{% set class = 'original_text' %}

{# Checkout the double quotes #}
{% set class = "#{class} some_other_text" %}
```

and can be used like this too:

```
{% set class = "#{class} some_other_text #{class}" %}
{{class}}
```

This last one will show an output like "original_text some_other_text original_text"